# Windows equivalent of Mac OSX Cmd + Left/Cmd + Right shortcuts

Tags: windows, macos, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, text-editing

When in text editors on a Mac, you can do <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>←</kbd> or <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>→</kbd> to skip to the beginning or end of lines, respectively.

You can also add <kbd>shift</kbd>, such as <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>←</kbd>, to highlight an entire line.

Are there Windows equivalents to any of these? <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>←</kbd> won't go to the beginning of a line, it will just skip back a word.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

<kbd>Home</kbd> to go to the beginning of the line.

<kbd>End</kbd> to go to the end of the line.

<kbd>Home</kbd> and then <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>End</kbd> or vice versa to highlight the entire line.

Additionally,

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>←</kbd>/<kbd>→</kbd> will just move one word like you mentioned.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Home</kbd>/<kbd>End</kbd> will move to the beginning/end of the document.

Comment: These shortcuts work great on my Dell laptop's keyboard because `Home` is mapped to `Fn`+`←`. But on my external keyboard, `Home` and `End` are in their classic positions, which I find much more awkward.

Comment: It looks like the kbd tags don't work in comments. If you would like to manually remap keys, consider [AutoHotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/).